# failing to display array entered from keyboard in c

Tags: c

I'm new to c and I'm trying to write a c program that get 10 integer values entered from keyboard using `scanf` and then print them using `printf` but the result is not correct. Here is the code:

```
   #include<stdio.h>
    #include<conio.h>
    main(){
     int x[10];
     printf("\n\n\t\t PRGRAM THAT CAPTURES AND PRINTS 10 SCORES");
     for(int i=1;i<=10;i++){
     printf("\n\tEnter Score %d", i);
     scanf("%d",x);
    }
     printf("\n\t The entered scores are: %d",x[i]);
     return(0);
    }
```

the output given is a four digit number like 8731 yet I expect something like 1234567890. some help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<conio.h>
    int main(){
     int x[10];
     printf("\n\n\t\t PRGRAM THAT CAPTURES AND PRINTS 10 SCORES");
     for(int i=0;i<10;i++){ //Change 1
         printf("\n\tEnter Score %d", i);
         scanf("%d",&x[i]); //Change 2
      }
     //Change 3
     for (int i=0; i<10; i++) 
         printf("\n\t The entered scores are: %d",x[i]);
     return(0);
    }
```

Comment: Btw, this is not `C` but a 'C++' code, so it might not compile on a `C` compiler

Comment: Thank you so much. Your code gave an error of multiple declaration of `i` which I fixed and all is fine now. What do you mean this is not "c" code?

Comment: The error you get is because you most probably using an nonstandard compiler, because `int i` declaration in the for loop should be only in the scope of that for loop.

Comment: And it is not `C` code because in pure `C` all the variables should be declared at the beginning of the method, you can not declare them when you need it, this is only allowed in `C++`

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a new `for` loop to display the values, just like you do when reading them.

PS: format your code better, you'll thank it later.

PS2: try to avoid `conio.h`, it's not standard, and you don't even need it for your code.

PS3: also your code is wrong. Should be `for(int i=0;i<10;i++)`. Arrays go from `0` to `size-1`, not from `1` to `size`. The C compiler will **not** warn you that `i[10]` is an **invalid** index for your array.

Comment: I could but I won't. It's **very** similar to your `for` reading loop. Try to make it yourself, it's a good exercise for you being a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

```
   #include<stdio.h>
    #include<conio.h>
```

The header `<conio.h>` is not standard. You get better portability if you don't use it. Anyway, your program doesn't use anything from it.

```
    main(){
```

The function `main()` returns an `int`. Get into the habit of saying so explicitly (and you might also get into the habit of objectively specifying it takes no parameters).

```
     int x[10];
     printf("\n\n\t\t PRGRAM THAT CAPTURES AND PRINTS 10 SCORES");
```

For better working of `printf()` in all implementation, end each one with a `'\n'`. Otherwise the output might appear out of order.

```
     for(int i=1;i<=10;i++){
     printf("\n\tEnter Score %d", i);
     scanf("%d",x);
```

Trying to always read to the same position in the array in a loop?

```
    }
     printf("\n\t The entered scores are: %d",x[i]);
```

The element `x[i]` does not exist. At this point in the code, `i` is larger than the largest legal array index.

```
     return(0);
    }
```

Comment: Also: `for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)`